# Why should the input range of the MNIST dataset be between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, mnist

I'm a MNIST beginner.
I have few questions. Here is one of them.

I stored the MNIST dataset in a csv file.(It's range between 0 and 255)

I trained these data, and I got the wrong answer, all 0.

But when I divided the dataset values ​​with 255, got the correct values.(It's range betwwen 0 and 1)

So, Why should the input range of the MNIST dataset be between 0 and 1?

I used the code from the MNIST tutorial.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y),reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
```